# Compute the differences between the elements of two lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, numpy

I want to subtract the element of two list from each other and make a list out them with a clean and efficient code in python:

For Example, given two lists `[2,7,8]`, `[1,9]`, subtracting(pairwise) the elements would give: `[1, 7, 6, 2, 7, 1]`.

I came up with two codes:

Code 1 :

```
l1,l2 = [1], [3,4]
l3,l4 = [2,7,8], [1,9]

def computedifference(list1,list2):
  output = []
  for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
      output.append(abs(i-j))
  return output
print(computedifference(l1,l2))
print(computedifference(l3,l4))
```

Code 2:

```
import numpy as np 

l1,l2 = [1], [3,4]
l3,l4 = [2,7,8], [1,9]

def computedifference(list1,list2):
  output1 = [ np.asarray(list1)-x for x in np.asarray(list2)]
  output = [np.abs(x) for x in output1]
  return output
print(computedifference(l1,l2))
print(computedifference(l3,l4))
```

Expected output

```
[2, 3]
[1, 7, 6, 2, 7, 1]
```

Is there a better, pythonic and efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

Most Pythonic way to efficiently calculate the cartesian product of iterables and subtract the results.

## Solution

The simplest and most pythonic approach:

```
[ abs(i-j) for i,j in itertools.product(list1, list2) ]
```

Depending on how large your dataset is, you may need to use a generator expression instead.

```
( abs(i-j) for i,j in itertools.product(list1, list2) )
```

Note that you don't need to explicitly define l1 and l2 since itertools.product takes `n` iterables. You can simply do:

```
l = [[1], [3,4]]

( abs(i-j) for i,j in itertools.product(*l) )
```

## References

itertools.product: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

generator expressions: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/

Answer (score 3):

Let's try `outer`:

```
np.abs(np.subtract.outer(l3,l4)).ravel()
```

Output:

```
array([1, 7, 6, 2, 7, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
def computedifference(list1,list2):
    return [abs(i-j) for i,j in itertools.product(list1,list2)]
```

documentation for itertools.product : https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to vectorize the pairwise difference:

```py
import numpy as np
l1, l2 = [1], [3,4]
l3, l4 = [2,7,8], [1,9]

def computedifference(list1, list2):
    l1 = np.array(list1)
    l2 = np.array(list2)
    
    return np.abs(l1[:,None] - l2).ravel().tolist()


computedifference(l1,l2)
[2, 3]

computedifference(l3,l4)
[1, 7, 6, 2, 7, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use python generator like this

```py
output = [abs(i - j) for i in list1 for j in list2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
>>> np.abs(a[:, np.newaxis] - b).flatten()
array([1, 7, 6, 2, 7, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l1 = [2,7,8]
l2 = [1,9]

def computedDiff(list1,list2):
    return([abs(i-j) for i in list1 for j in list2])

print(computedDiff(l1,l2))
```

Ok so basically what I did here is compressed it to one line, and and am just returning the entire for loop in list form. Just a cleaner way since it does not include any other variables or appending to a list.